# Python how to read and split a line to several integers

Tags: python, file-io

For input file separate by space/tab like:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

How to read the line and split the integers, then save into either lists or tuples? Thanks.

```
data = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
data = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way to do this, assuming the sublists are on separate lines:

```
with open("filename.txt", 'r') as f:
    data = [map(int, line.split()) for line in f]
```

Note that the `with` statement didn't become official until Python 2.6.  If you are using an earlier version, you'll need to do

```
from __future__ import with_statement
```

Comment: +1 this is closest to the way I'd do it, and I think the best example of "best practices" (whatever that means) of the 5 answers here.

Answer (score 3):

If you find yourself dealing with matrices or tables of numbers, may I suggest numpy package?

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt(input_filename)
```

Answer (score 2):

tuples = [tuple(int(s) for s in line.split()) for line in open("file.txt").readlines()]

I like [Jeff's `map(int, line.split())`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122121/python-how-to-read-and-split-a-line-to-several-integers/3122147#3122147), instead of the inner generator.

Comment: Does this way really store a splited line into a tuple? Can you please explain a bit more? Thanks.

Comment: Actually this will give you a list of lists, not a list of tuples (because `str.split` returns a list). Basically what it does is open the file, read in its lines, then iterate through them (`for tup in ...`) and split each one on whitespace.

Comment: So how to store in a tuple? That is part of my original question. Thanks.

Comment: @David : the OP said lists or tuples, but good call, thanks, edited.  @Stan : just construct a tuple from the list.

Comment: @Stephen: yep, my comment was directed to Stan's comment above mine, not so much at your answer. Sorry for not making that clear.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You mean, like this?</strike>

**update**

Just convert each string into int

```
string = """1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9"""

data = []
for line in string.split("\n"):    #split by new line
    data.append( map( int, line.split(" ") ) ) # split by spaces and add 

print( data )
```

Output:

<strike>[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]</strike>

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Da daaaa!!!

Comment: I end up using mapping function. Still didn't figure out another way to convert all read in string into a integer.

Comment: Oh, I thought you had that already I misread your *I end up using...*

Answer (score 1):

```
def getInts(ln):
    return [int(word) for word in ln.split()]

f = open('myfile.dat')
dat = [getInts(ln) for ln in f]
```