# Finding mean of column data in certain interval

Tags: ubuntu, awk, numerical-methods

I come across that `awk` can be used to find the mean of the column as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3122442/1977614). Let's say I would like to compute the average of the second column, but only elements between specific rows (for example, from rows 2 up to 6). How to do this?

Comment: Read [ask] and then [edit] your question to provide the missing info.

Comment: @EdMorton: I went through the "How to ask" section. But I do not exactly see what is the missing information. Any specific pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. `awk` has parameter `FNR` implying number of records typically indicating the  line number. Using this on karakfa's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39709432/1977614):

```
awk 'FNR>=2 && FNR<=6 {sum+=$2; count++} 
   END {print (count?sum/count:"N/A")}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '$2>=2 && $2<=6 {sum+=$2; count++} 
                  END {print (count?sum/count:"N/A")}' file
```

Comment: This does not work for data in scientific format. For example, +5.68902179E+00

Comment: I realized that my question lacked some clarity. I made the edit. What I meant is accessing columns between specific row intervals and not columns between specific values.

Comment: Found the solution using `FNR`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$ awk -v s=2 -v e=6  '{if(($2>=s)&&($2<=e)){sum+=$2;n++}}END{print (n!=0)?sum/n:0}' input.txt
```

Explanation:

```
#!/bin/awk

BEGIN {
    start = 2
    end = 6
}

{
    if( ($2 >= start) && ($2 <= end) )
    {
        sum = sum + $2
        n = n + 1
    }
}

END {
    print ( n!= 0) ? sum / n : 0
}

#eof#
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: `NR` won't be the number of records summed up!  You have to use the actual count for mean computation.

Comment: Now you have to handle `n==0` case, otherwise you'll get `fatal: division by zero attempted` error.

Comment: Writing `{ if (condition) action }` in awk is like writing `if (true) { if (condition) action } }` in C.  Hopefully you wouldn't write that in C so don't write the equivalent in awk, it's just `condition { action }`. By the time you fix the issues with your answer, though, it'll be the same as @karakfa's answer.